# Is it possible to pass parameters into a translated sentence in a .po translation file?

Tags: parameters, gettext, translate

I am using `.po` and `.mo` files for translating my website.
My question is, is it possible to pass parameters into a translated sentence in a [.po translation file](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gettext/PO-Files.html)?

For example:
en ->  Hi, my name is Sarah, and I am an alcoholic
I want to translate that sentence using two params, name (Sarah) and profession (an alcoholic).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the language, but basically, yes, you always can.

```
printf(_("Hi, my name is %s and I am %s"), name, prof);
```

in c.

```
echo sprintf(_("Hi, my name is %s and I am %s"), $name, $prof);
```

in php.

```
alert( _('Hi, my name is %s and I am %s')
    .replace('%s',name).replace('%s',prof) );
```

in javascript or better something like:

```
alert( _('Hi, my name is %1 and I am %2')
    .replace('%1',name).replace('%2',prof) );
```

or whatever you can come up with for a placeholder. Javascript implementation of course relies on having the translation mechanism provided either at preprocessing time or as a runtime underscore function.

and so forth.

Comment: Reaaally old topic, but had to say a potential bug: "Hola, soy un Francisco llamado alcoholico" ("Hello, I am a Francisco called alcoholic"). There are many ways to translate the sentence, and this is a proof of a right translation but wrong result from gettext.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to say. Definitely, gettext may have yield wrong results if used some wrong way. You may simply mistranslate the original, you may translate the original without paying much attention to grammar (case, gender, etc.), you may have one original that should be translated differently depending on the context (this one is easies to work around). What I don't get is why many ways to translate are a proof of a right translation but wrong gettext result?

Comment: Lol I never expected an answer here. I just meant that a text string with two parameters in one order for one language could be translated into a string with the parameters in different order for the other language. While the first is the name and the second the profession in English, it could be that the first is the profession and the second is the name for Spanish. Except the second case of javascript which looks like it will work good.

Comment: There are different substitution mechanisms. In gnu (at least) c `*printf*` family functions will work with `%1$s`, `%2$s` placeholders in *translated* string. (Why not answer once notified?:))

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but just to mention...

In many languages you can also indicate what argument want to use, like this (in PHP):

```
$name = 'Agustinus';
printf(_("Hi %1$s.\n The owner of this page is: %1$s. Today is %s.", 
   $name, date('d-m-Y'));
```

Comment: The `%1$s` (note, it's not `%$1s`) may be supported by php on all platforms, but the origin is gnu libc, I believe. Worth noting, though, that if you use `%1$s` you may not use `%s` in the same string and you're also not allowed to have gaps in numbering.